# Why prepared statements are managed by each session?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, rdbms

Why prepared statements are managed by each session?

I am not sure all of databases handle prepared statements per session. but postgresql and mysql(maybe) do.

Why they are not shared between session? Is there any reason?

For example, 
There are many connections in connection pool and connections share same queries and also generate same prepared statements. Why database does not let connections share prepared statement?

Comment: Because the statement is kept prepared over a connection and each connection is associated with one session?

Comment: What do you mean 'each connection is associated with one session'?

Comment: How should they be managed otherwise? Why would they be shared? How would you share them? Are you aware of implications? What would you gain? You can't just ask a question if you don't know the answer to inverse of your question.

Comment: They are identified by a simple name. I think it would be too easy to create conflicts if it was shared.

Comment: @Mjh If they knew all that, they wouldn't be asking. If you know all that, I don't, perhaps you could write up an answer.

Comment: "Why" questions are candidates for closure because the answers are opinion based, and I can only answer for PostgreSQL. One reason is that it is much simpler to implement this in backend process private memory than in shared memory. Another reason is that it is difficult to share statements between different users - think of row level security, where every user sees different data.

Comment: Almost every RDBMS will create a process at server side for each connection.  Some of them indeed have a statements cache so that if you execute exactly the same SQL over two different connections it might be precompiled. However, other resource may be associated with the connection. For example, think about autocommit. Statements are created over the connections and the autocommit is a parameter of the connection. If the statement could be associated with two connections then it'd be at the very least necessary to specify which one to one when calling statement.execute(sql)

Comment: @Mjh I appended the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining any shared cache is expensive - you should to protect cache against race condition, you should to clean cache, ... This is first argument. Second argument is more important - prepared statement is cached execution plan - but this plan is optimized for one vector of parameters. When you are using different parameter's vector, then plan can be suboptimal again this vector. There is a philosophy, so any user can uses different vectors and then needs different plans. Using session shared plan cache doesn't eliminate overhead from generating plans (although this overhead is for fast simple queries minimal), but eliminates overhead and race conditions related to management of shared data, and partially reduce risk of using suboptimal prepared plans.